# Updating background colour using batchUpdate in Google Apps Script API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use Google Apps Scripts batchUpdate to update the styling of a range of cells.

I have put together the very simple example to hopefully enable me to get started, however I am getting the following error message back from this.

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field. at updateGoogleSheet(fullSheet/fullSheet:316)

My code to try and do the update is as follows

```
    var data = {
        requests: [{
            updateCell: {
                range: 'Sheet3!A3',
                cell: {
                    userEnteredFormat: {
                        backgroundColor: {
                            red: 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                fields: 'userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor)'
            }
        }]
    };

    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(data, spreadsheetId);
```

Comment: It would be a lot cleaner to get and set formatting for ranges rather than bath updating cells, why are you choosing to do it this way?

Comment: It’s because I need to set a lot of different formats at once over a variety of ranges so thought it would be better if I could do it in a batch so I don’t hit concurrency limits which I was before doing individual ranges. Unless you know of a different way which won’t hit the limits of google?

Comment: I think you should try it with RangeLists, concurrency won't apply because you aren't going through the advanced api.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is to declare a rangelist and apply formatting to those in bulk.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['A:A', 'C:C','D4']);
rangeList.setBackground('red');

sheet.getRangeList(['B3','F6').setFontFamily("Roboto");
```

Comment: Will this handle hundreds of different ranges though all with different formats? Potentially I’ll have thousands that need processing all different so it’s not like I can just set the format for a large range they all may be different per cell? Will this run into max concurrent thresholds doing it this way?

Comment: max concurrent is only going to be api related. You might run out of processing time, but I'd test 100 and see how long it takes.

Comment: I’ve seen an exception of too many simultaneous events being fired before on the GAS side, should this be ok with this? I’ll give it a try tomorrow and get back to you!

Comment: another option is creating arrays of colors, weights, etc and then applying them as a set

Comment: Actually the one I’m interested in particularly is the pattern, could this be done as a set? Do you have any snippets you can share?

Comment: they won't be simultaneous, they will apply one range at a time as it goes through the function

Comment: Look at this article : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices it explains how to preload formatting cell by cell in an array and then mass apply: sheet.getRange(1, 1, 100, 100).setBackgroundColors(colors);

Comment: That’s great thanks so much for the info I’ll give these a go tomorrow